# In Unity, how to animate upper body with kinect and lower body with mecanim animation

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I am working in unity. I want to animate characters upper body with kinect and lower body with animation controller. when i use animator with "kinect character controller" then kinect animation are not applying on then character, even when i use avatar mask with animators layer. then the disable parts in the avatar mask are become static(neither moving with animation and nor with kinect).

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. I encourage you to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve the quality of your question.  Otherwise, you may not receive the help you seek.

Comment: Please use unity3d tag for such.

Comment: finally found the solution. Using "Kinect with MS-SDK" plugin for unity
i- add "Avatar Controller Classic" script to character.
ii- only assign those bones that you want to animate with kinect & set smoothing factor to 0.
iii- Now add animation controller to animator component of character.
iv- assign "avatar mask" to animator controllers layer. and disable those parts of mask which you assign to "Avatar controller classic" script.